# Delete image background on click - several images

Tags: android, background

I need some help with simple logic. There are 3 buttons. On click, I set as a background a picture, either chosen from the gallery, or taken by a camera. As a global var I define checked1 and give it value "false". On click - it is changed to true. The problem is with the delete method. Via a frame layout, I attach a clipper to each of the photos. On click of the clipper, a dialog appears, asking if to delete the photo. here is my problem - how can I delete the photo clicked (now it deletes always the first one, as the first if is entered). Uploaded 1/2/3 vars are global booleans, that turn to TRUE on the button's click. Here is the not-working delete method:

```
if (uploaded1) {
        imageUploader1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.---));
        editImage1.setImageDrawable(null);

    } else if (uploaded2) {
        imageUploader2.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable
               .---));
        editImage2.setImageDrawable(null);
    } else if (uploaded3) {
        imageUploader3.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable
                .---));
        editImage3.setImageDrawable(null);
```

The onButtonClick:

```
imageUploader.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            textImage.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.blue_300));
            clicked4 = true;
            showDialog();
        }
    });
```

The showDialog() asks for a choice between a camera and a gallery as a source. Then, in the onActivityResult() the code looks like that:

```
 if (clicked1) {

               imageUploader1.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),photo));
               pathImg1 = getOriginalImagePath();
            editImage1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_mode_edit_black_24dp);
               clicked1 = false;
               uploaded1 = true;
 }
```

Comment: Can you show the complete code of your OnButtonClickListener method?

Comment: I've updated the code, please, have a look.